# How to read raw data, say only text, from a file(word document, excel) without format?

Tags: java, excel, file, file-read

I have a file plain.doc. It has some text in it.
Now i added some format to the text in the plain.doc. I have added background color to the document and changed the color, font and style of the text and saved it as formatted.doc.

In my application i am reading the file by
***byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();***

When i upload plain.doc, ***bytes*** size was 11000 bytes.
When i upload formatted.doc, ***bytes*** size was 29000 bytes.

I have same text in both the files.

Is there any way in java to read only the raw text of a file without its format?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=java+word First hit: [Apache POI - the Java API for Microsoft Documents](https://poi.apache.org/)

Comment: You are going to need to use a library to handle this.